# Which is the standard way to retrieve the totality of a packet from a networkstream in VB.NET?

Tags: c++, vb.net, sockets

Hello as a c++ programmer, the lack of pointers really annoys more than wrappers would help me.

I want to receive a packet without my data being truncated should i use a byte array and sequentially stack the data? or should i use a memorystream?

the point is my data comes in structure like this for example

char Signature[8]
DWORD Length
char Data[Length]

in c++ i used a vector to store the incoming data in a growing buffer untill the Length was reach.

Whats the right way to do it in VB.net?

When i needed to transfer numbers i transfer them in its binary representation cause its more efficient and in c++ is just a cast away.

I found in vb.net the need to use a binaryreader in order to cast its data to a Uint32.

I am stuck between all this wrappers I feel they make the work even more complicated.

The only reason i want to use vb is because the ease to integrate with GUI objects which are a real pain when dealing with MFC.

I am open to suggestions, would even consider to move to a different IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use Qt then? it's pretty easy

Comment: Thanks will check it out honestly never heard of it